# Finding the most commonly occuring pairs

Tags: algorithm

Say that I have a list (or array) that links Suppliers with the materials they supply. For example, an array of the form

```
[[Supplier_1, Material_a], [Supplier_2, Material_a], [Supplier_3, Material_a], [Supplier_1, Material_b], [Supplier_2, Material_c], [Supplier_3, Material_b], ...]
```

I am interested in finding the the list of suppliers that supply at least `k` materials that a particular supplier say `Supplier_1` supplies.

One way that I can think of is to pair all suppliers with `Supplier_1` for each material `Supplier_1` supplies

```
[[Supplier_1, Supplier_2, Material_a], [Supplier_1, Supplier_3, Material_a], [Supplier_1, Supplier_3, Material_b]...]
```

and then count the number of times each pair is present

```
[[Supplier_1, Supplier_2, 1], [Supplier_1, Supplier_3, 2]...]
```

The problem is that this approach can be very time consuming since the list provided can be quite long. I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You would put the materials of `Supplier_1` in a hash set, so that you can verify for any material whether it is supplied by `Supplier_1` in constant time.

Once you have that you can iterate the data again, and in a dictionary (hash map) keep a count per supplier which you increment each time the material is in the above mentioned set.

In Python it would look like this:

```py
def getsuppliers(pairs, selected_supplier, k):
    materialset = set()
    countmap = {} # a dictionary with <key=supplier, value=count> pairs
    for supplier, material in pairs:
        if supplier == selected_supplier:
            materialset.add(material)
        countmap[supplier] = 0

    # An optional quick exit: if the selected provider does not have k materials,
    #   there is no use in continuing...
    if countmap[selected_supplier] < k:
        return [] # no supplier meets the requirement

    for supplier, material in pairs:
        if material in materialset:
            countmap[supplier] = countmap[supplier]+1

    result = []
    for supplier, count in countmap.items():
        if count >= k:
            result.append(supplier)

    return result
```

NB: this would include the selected supplier also, provided it has at least *k* materials.

All operations within each individual loop body, have a constant time complexity, so the overall time complexity is *O(n)*, where *n* is the size of the input list (`pairs`).